# How to give the Shadow for layout(Relative or Linear)

Tags: android, layout, shadow

In android, i have listview and inside the listview adapter,i want to use some shadow in view layout.How to give the Shadow for layout(Relative or Linear) in android?

Comment: You need to explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve, as the question is quite unclear. Maybe include some of the source code you're working with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this all links please.
1) http://myandroidspace.blogspot.in/2012/01/android-styling-listview-rows-with.html

2) http://b2creativedesigns.comuv.com/ListView.html

3) [How to make gradient background in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android)

4) http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/User_Interface/Working_with_ListViews_and_Adapters/Part_3_-_Customizing_a_ListView's_Appearance

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: ok. friend, i accept your comment. I am new here so don't know the way how to answer the question. please edit my answer if you can. thanks