# Android small counter next to a button

Tags: android, button, counter

I would like to add a small counter next to a button to show the remaining quantity for some items, for example, the remaining number of tips remaining unused. Targeted layout would be as shown:

[image]

### Question:

I have researched the web and found that some say to use different pictures for each quantity. Yet how could it be solved if the quantity can be up to 100? Really necessary to draw such out?

I am thinking of to stick 2 buttons together in a `RelativeLayout` such that when the user presses the bottom button, the top button will count up and down and `setText` itself, but are there some better solutions or imports?

### Edit:

Thanks Rupesh for your codes and advice! I have implemented as follows. Yet do you know how to move the red circle textview further to the right? and the 20 cannot be properly shown in the red circle too...

[image]

### Code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_btn"
        android:onClick="button_tip_click"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: See my solution, using custom Drawable you can solve your both issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set Button's background Drawable to a custom Drawable like this one:

[image]

```
public class DecoratedTextViewDrawable extends LayerDrawable {
    private int mCnt = 0;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private TextView mParent;
    private ColorStateList mColors;
    private Rect mBounds;

    public DecoratedTextViewDrawable(TextView tv, Drawable[] layers, int cnt) {
        super(layers);
        mParent = tv;
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTextSize(tv.getTextSize());
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        int[][] states = {
                {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, {android.R.attr.state_focused}, {}
        };
        int[] colors = {
                0xff0000aa, 0xff880000, 0xff00aa00
        };
        mColors = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        mBounds = new Rect();
        setCnt(cnt);
    }

    public void setCnt(int cnt) {
        mCnt = cnt;
        String s = Integer.toString(cnt);
        mPaint.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), mBounds);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] state) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return super.onStateChange(state);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        float x = mPaint.getTextSize() * 1.5f;
        float r = mPaint.getTextSize() * 0.9f;
        int base = mParent.getBaseline();
        int[] stateSet = getState();
//        Log.d(TAG, "draw " + StateSet.dump(stateSet));
        int color = mColors.getColorForState(stateSet, 0xff000000);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, base + mBounds.top + mBounds.height() / 2, r, mPaint);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffeeeeee);
        canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(mCnt), x, base, mPaint);
    }
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
// Activity.onCreate method
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

int NUM = 5;
final int[] cnt = new int[NUM];
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    cnt[i] = r.nextInt(20);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Click me");
    b.setTextSize(18);
    b.setTag(i);

    Drawable[] layers = {b.getBackground()};
    Drawable d = new DecoratedTextViewDrawable(b, layers, cnt[i]);
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DecoratedTextViewDrawable  d = (DecoratedTextViewDrawable) v.getBackground();
            int idx = (Integer) v.getTag();
            d.setCnt(++cnt[idx]);
        }
    };
    b.setOnClickListener(l);
    ll.addView(b);
}
setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: many thanks, the code seem complex, i will investigate and revert!

Comment: complex? it simply decorates std background drawable of a Button, and does not need any extra FrameLayouts and TextViews, as simple as it could be

Answer (score 2):

use this - and keep updating the textviews text with the count

```
 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/your_phone_call_image"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:scaletype="matrix"/>

  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="1"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:gravity="top|right"  <!--this is important-->
     android:background="@drawable/your_counter_red_background"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your advice! I have implemented your codes and edited in the question...yet do you know how to move the red button further a bit to the right so that can see the text of the bottom button properly, and that the number in the circle be properly shown (i have tried before using wrap_content, yet then it is no circle anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use a FrameLayout.
1.- you can use 2 images one for your button, one for the little circle and use a textview for the numbers...
2.- you can use one image for your button, and create a gradient for the little circle and a text view..

For the frameLayout see :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html 
For the gradient see: [How to make gradient background in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android).