# Android: Adding badge to corner of drawable on a button

Tags: android, android-drawable

What is the best way to add a badge icon (Circle with a number in it) to a button's drawable?

The drawable is just an image. I was hoping there would be a way to change what I am using as the buttons drawable, and perhaps set it to another drawable that has my image in the middle with a shape on the top right. I will need to update the text of the shape programatically.

Here is my button now:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/SpecialsMenuButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:text="@string/specials_tab_title"
     android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:drawableBottom="@drawable/collections_labels"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I also created a circle badge:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <solid
    android:color="#F00" />
  <stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFF" />
  <padding
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

I want to as easily as possible replace the `android:drawableBottom` with something that will have my image with the shape in the top right corner of the image. Will I be able to do this as a drawable or will I have to do this outside of the button?

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009810/android-small-counter-next-to-a-button/19010184#19010184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it as a `Drawable` you have to create a `Bitmap` where you draw the circle and the number onto the image of the button.

But I would do it like this: Place the badge as an `ImageView` and a `TextView` above your button, so you can easily edit the text of the `TextView`

Comment: I believe I follow what you are saying. But just to clarify, when you say "above your button", do you mean as in a layer above the button?

Comment: @PFranchise Yes, I mean that the button is followed by an ImageView (or the View which shows the shape) and a TextView in the layout file, so it get's shown on top of the button.
This will work in a `RelativeLayout` with correct positioning

Comment: creating two Views plus a Container that wraps them is just waste of time amd resources, see my comment above how to do it just by decorating original Drawable