# Xml - background with lines

Tags: android, xml, background, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How I can do same background using xml [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmWFA.png)

Comment: prefer to use adobe or Figma for such kind of complex backgrounds.

Comment: I solve my problem use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967330/custom-background-with-layer-list-to-show-diagonal-lines