# Defining multi-color gradients

Tags: java, android, gradient

first post here. Also excuse me in case any of this is glaringly obvious. I am a total newbie at xml & java and mainly a designer.

I want to implement the design I created in Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop for an app I am working on. I know you can use XML with start/center/end color for basic gradients. But I want to create exactly the one I designed, with as many colors as desired and custom intervals where they start and end. I found this solution in another thread:

```
ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory shaderFactory = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
            new int[] { 
                0xFF1e5799, 
                0xFF207cca, 
                0xFF2989d8, 
                0xFF207cca }, //substitute the correct colors for these
            new float[] {
                0, 0.40f, 0.60f, 1 },
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
         return linearGradient;
    }
};
PaintDrawable paint = new PaintDrawable();
paint.setShape(new RectShape());
paint.setShaderFactory(shaderFactory);
```

How do I include colors I manually defined via values/colors? It doesn't let me use @color/darkgrey etc. obviously, as they are not integer. Also I cannot put them in in hexa-code for probably the same reason.

I'd like to do new int [] {@color/A, @color/B, ...}

Also, second question: the float seems to define the custom intervals from which the colors are used. In his example he had 4 int colors, and 4 float values - but that would only define 3 intervals from what I understand (?):
[0,0.4] [0.4,0.6] [0.6,1] in percentages.
Or does it work in a different way?

I'll specify further details, if neccessary.

Comment: From
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android/13968524#13968524
what do you mean by "It doesn't let me use @color/darkgrey etc" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I include colors I manually defined via values/colors?

If you want to use color resource values in java, you will need access to a `Context` object or one of its subclasses (like `Activity`). Then you can call

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color_name);
```

> the float seems to define the custom intervals from which the colors are used

Not exactly. The `float[]` values define the point from `0` to `1` where each color is placed. So if you have four colors, you'll want four positions (and the first and last should be 0 and 1).

With that in mind, you could write something like this:

```
int[] colors = new int[] {
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_one),
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_two),
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_three),
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_four);
};

float[] positions = new float[] {
    0, 0.33, 0.67, 1
};

LinearGradient linearGradient = 
    new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height, colors, positions, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

This would produce a gradient from:

- `color_one` to `color_two` at `0` to `0.33`
- `color_two` to `color_three` at `0.33` to `0.67`
- `color_three` to `color_four` at `0.67` to `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I was a bit confused regarding the context argument, however I replaced it with LoginActivity.this (the one it's applied in) and it worked, after some Google search. How do I now also influence the angle? That's the last thing missing, currently it's diagonal.

Comment: The first four arguments (in my example, `0, 0, width, height`) are two points, so my example gradient draws from `(0,0)` to `(width,height)`. The relative positioning of the two points defines the angle.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben's answer is complete and answers most of your questions. To answer also the last point

> Also I cannot put them in in hexa-code for probably the same reason.

In Java you prepend '0x' to indicate an hexa notation. Colors are expressed as ARGB (Alpha/R/G/B), so the expressions

```
int red = 0xffff0000, blue = 0xff0000ff, green = 0xff00ff00;
int red_half_alpha = 0x80ff0000;
```

are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification regarding the 0x, know I understand how to apply that; using the above method Ben provided would be better in terms of consistency, though, and also to avoid having to look up ARGBs all the time, I assume?

Comment: yeah, the less stuff hardcoded the better, of course, just wanted to tell you how to use hex values in Java should you need it sometime :)