# Android : How to Create Dividers between Components

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

My goal is to obtain divider lines similar to the ones shown in the following picture:
[Goal Picture Divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37UOY.jpg)

I need to place a horizontal and vertical divider between **LinearLayout**

This is my User Interface XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/maingradiant">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="اطلاعات ورودی"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="فاکتور"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="هزینه ها"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="تسویه"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="سامانه"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ارسال بار"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am currently using **RelativeLayout** as the *Root Element*, and for each row, I am applying a horizontal **LinearLayout** followed by a vertical **LinearLayout**.
Based on my current layout, can I receive assistance on how to place the divider lines on my interface, much like the provided picture?
Thank you!

Comment: Use DividerLines in GridLayout.

Comment: My Main Layout Is LinearLayot

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: @AndroDevil My Layout Is LinearLayout ... Main Subject Divider ... No Grid Need I Only Need Put Divider Between Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recomend you to use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager for this purpose. [creating recyclerview with gridmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587168/5235032)

but if you want stick with current design, you add line by creating a View in xml

For Vertical line

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp" //thickness 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

For Horizontal line

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="2dp"//thickness
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

for shading colors you should look for something like Gradient in android. [How ro create Gradient in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13929877/5235032)

code looks like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/maingradiant"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="اطلاعات ورودی"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="فاکتور"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="هزینه ها"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="تسویه"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="سامانه"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheatallergyambericon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ارسال بار"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you . Work Great .