# How to make transparent glass color background

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a Layout button like the one in this photo with a transparent glassy color.

[image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/glassColor"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
</shape>
```

I have the drawable, but I can't figure out how to create a hex color like the one in the picture

Comment: Try a [gradient background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android) .. Alternatively you can use an image as background ..

Comment: for you, it is better to use a blur effect on the background of your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the answer you are looking for but if you create a new color value @color/ you can access the built in color pane to set the color transparency.
I am sure you know this by now and surely my answer is not what you have expected.

```
<color name="colortransparent">#4F784A06</color>
```

Comment: That color is perfect. I've tried white #4FFFFFFF i.imgur.com/ftHzm8D.png but it just doesn't look good. How did you decide on that color? Do you have a tool that picks the best hex color?

Comment: Thank you so much. Its the custom color picker on Android Studio.