# How do you make a line drawable with a gradient?

Tags: android, xml, shapes, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

So...I wanted to add a line that looks like this [line with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCjkf.png)
and have created a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">

        <stroke
            android:color="#000000"
            android:width="1dp"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFEE8D85"
            android:endColor="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

which gives this result [line without gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDz5o.png)
what do I do to get the desired result I want?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android. I think, you should remove `rotate` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make drawable resourse file.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#14b19e"
        android:endColor="#115ede" />
</shape>
```

Then apply like this

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_gradient_drawable"/>
```